# C++ parenthesis matching application

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl, stack

I have to write a function that accepts a string and returns a bool. The string passed in is a series or different parenthesis opened or closed ex.({[]}) and returns whether the 'parens' are well-balanced. This has to be implemented by adding items to a stack. I am getting the following error:

> parenMatching_demo.cpp:18:12: error: no match for 'operator==' in 'c
>   == '('

The psudocode is:

```
matcher(expression) 
    for each character in expression 
        if  the character is an opener
            push on stack
        else if the character is a closr
            if stack is empty return false
            if the (opener at) the top of the stack does not match the closer
                return false
            pop the stack

     if the stack is not empty return false
     return true
```

This is what I have.

```
template <typename T>   
bool parenMatching(string c) {
    stack<string> s;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
        if (c == '(' || c == '[' || c == '{' || c == '<')
            s.push(c);
        else if (c == ')' || c == ']' || c == '}' || c == '>') {
            if (s.empty()) return false;
            if (s.top() != '(' || s.top() != '[' || s.top() != '{' || s.top() != '<')
                return false;
            s.pop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is not crazy. Please tell us exactly what it says.

Comment: post what the error is

Comment: i dont really know, it is some long error and when i the beginning part of the error gets cut off.

Comment: What do you use the `typename T` for? It looks like `T` don't appear in your code. Why do you define a `template`?

Comment: Here i got the error it is. parenMatching_demo.cpp:18:12: error: no match for 'operator==' in 'c == '(''

Comment: Your solution is a bit complex. It can be [made much simpler](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=2b8e21e9978d8b8dad8ac35f4c4fd59b-1f48a68887043b2645051583fb11641d).

Comment: @Rapptz Your solution is wrong though. It only checks that the number of opening brackets equal the number of closing brackets, which is not the requirement. Look at the pseudo-code.

Comment: @Rapptz: For instance, parenMatch(")))(((") returns true, but should return false.

Comment: @Bill Yeah I got that after I posted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One problem is the type of the stack, it should be

```
stack<char> s;
```

Then the `for` loop, the condition should be

```
i < c.size()
```

The next problem is

```
if (c == '(' || c == '[' || c == '{' || c == '<')
```

does not compare the character of the string `c` at `i`, so you need

```
const char c2 = c[i];
if (c2 == '(' || c2 == '[' || c2 == '{' || c2 == '<')
```

If you need help to fix the rest, let me/us know :)

Comment: that did not really change anyting

Comment: @FJam The first problem I spotted or the current answer?

Comment: ok that got rid of the other error. but no it says, undefined reference to `parenMatching(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
In the main I called the function by saying parenMathching("({[]})");

Comment: @FJam Hm, actually I don't see any reason for the `template<typename T>`. Does removing it help?

Answer (score 2):

You're comparing a string with a char in your codes that check for the parentheses. You're missing a line where you get the current character you're looking at as you iterate your string - you probably want something like:

```
char current = c.at(i);
```

Additionally, you need to fix your stack type as Daniel Frey says in his answer.

edit - he's since changed his to contain this info, so that answer should have everything you need.